# Prove that $f(R) = \{ y \in P\ | \; (\exists x \in R)\; f(x) = y \; \} $ is a subring of ring $P$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f$ be a homomorphism of ring $R$ into ring $P$. Prove that $f(R) = \{ y \in P\ | \; (\exists x \in R)\;  f(x) = y \;   \} $ is a subring of ring $P$.


What would be a good way to prove this? I know how to do subring test, but I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: I don't think you can both "know how to do the subring test" and "not know how to use it" at the same time.  You have a set. You know its elements. You have some criteria to check on those elements.  The only thing that could prevent you from moving forward is either lack of trying, or not understanding the criteria to begin with!  It would be very helpful to know what you had already started writing. You have started a solution, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be really annoying, you need to check that $0_P\in f(R)$, $1_P\in f(R)$ if they are unital, and that if $f(r),f(s)\in f(R)$ then $f(r)-f(s)\in f(R)$ and $f(r)\cdot f(s)\in f(R)$. Essentially, you have to prove that $f(R)$ is a subgroup with respect to $+$ and a subsemigroup (or submonoid, if they are unital) with respect to $\cdot$. Now, try to use the definition of ring homomorphism.

Comment: Ring does not necessarily contain unity.

Comment: Indeed, but if they are, one usually requires preservation of units as far as I know. Anyway, I edited the submonoid part, for the sake of the reader